# <div> height rendering issue with Firefox

Tags: firefox, html, height, rendering

I created a div that transitions from a beginning height to a larger height, revealing a list. It looks fine in web-kit browsers but in Firefox the div appears to come up short, cutting off the bottom of the list.

I tried setting the div height in `em` hoping that the div would then match the height to the font size used in the list. Still the same thing occurs.

Any ideas?

CSS:

```
#nav{
        padding:0;
        position:fixed;
        top:27px;
        left:27px;
        font-family:arial;
        font-size:10px;
        background-color:#ccc;
        width:11.3em;
        height:5.5em;
        overflow:hidden;
        transition: height .5s;
        -webkit-transition: height .5s; /* Safari */
    }
    #nav:hover{
        height:22em;
    }
    #nav a.bg:hover{
       background-color: #ccc;
    }
    #nav a{
       text-decoration:none;
       color:#000;   
    }
    #nav a:hover{
       background-color:#6a6a6a;

    }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="top">
    <div id="nav">
        <!--logo_image-->

            <a class="bg" href="#"><img src="b&w_logo.jpeg" height="56" width="110" /></a>

        <!---->

            <div style="height:1em;"></div>
            <div style="font-size:1.1em;"><b>Artists</b></div>
            <div style="height:1em;"></div>
            <div><a href="#">Ahnnu</a></div>
            <div><a href="#">Gem Vision</a></div>
            <div><a href="#">Dope Body</a></div>
            <div><a href="#">Co La</a></div>
            <div><a href="#">Teenage Souls</a></div>
            <div><a href="#">Kid Krusher</a></div>
            <div><a href="#">Lil Jabba</a></div>
            <div><a href="#">Cex</a></div>
            <div><a href="#">Teeth Mountain</a></div>
            <div><a href="#">Jimmy joe Roche</a></div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you add your code, or a JSFiddle?

Comment: just updated post with the code added. thanks for checking it out.

Comment: I think I figured it out(was driving me mad for a while...) - firefox sets default line-height differently - setting an explicit line height seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: Good work, glad you got it sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

U have 2 options I think:
One is called CSS reset - http://html5reset.org/

The second one is called Normalize. Instead of resetting all styles, it targets the ones that need to change to give you sane, consistent results across browsers in a smaller file size. http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/